# rakefile questions with Sequel commands

Tags: ruby, sequel, rakefile

I am looking over some code and I don't understand some lines. Here is the code:

```
require "bundler"
Bundler.require

namespace :db do
  desc "Setup database"
  task :setup do
    Sequel.extension :migration
    @database = Sequel.postgres "sequel-playground"
  end

  desc "Run migrations"
  task :migrate => [:setup] do
    Sequel::Migrator.run(@database, "db")
  end

  desc "Reset database"
  task :reset => [:setup] do
    Sequel::Migrator.run(@database, "db", :target => 0)
    Sequel::Migrator.run(@database, "db")
  end
end
```

I understand the lines involvin bundler, namespace, desc, and task. However, I do not understand these things...

-What is the line Sequel.extension :migration doing?
-The @database = Sequel.postgres lins "sequel-playground line is just setting up an instance variable that is equal to a Sequel database object? Is that right?
-In the line:

```
Sequel:: Migrator.run(@database, "db")
```

Is Sequel the module, is Migrator a class and is run a method? What are the two arguments doing?

-What is :target => 0 doing in the reset task?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
Sequel.extension :migration
```

Simple enables the migration extension manually for Sequel as it is not part of the core library.

[Migration Extension](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/migration_rdoc.html#label-The+migration+extension)

The line

```
Sequel.postgres
```

Opens up the database giving you an instance with which you can run commands on.

[Open Database](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html#label-Open+a+database)

As for the

```
Sequel::Migrator.run(@database, "db", :target => 0)
```

It simply tells Sequel to migrate the given database to the version 0 of the schema.

[Rake Migrations](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/migration_rdoc.html#label-Running+migrations+from+a+Rake+task)

The documentation usually has all the answers for these things.

Comment: Thanks, I still have trouble reading the documentation... it simply just doesn't make sense to met yet. What is a schemas? How are they different from the migration files in db?

Comment: Migration files individually alter the database schema. The result of running the migration files would be a schema. Therefore going back to version 0 of the schema essentially means rolling back all the migration files. That's a completely different question from what you're originally asking though.